# I need to create a function where if suppose s[1] has already been occupied by X or O to show warning that its invalid choice

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int check();
void board();
int s[10]= {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
```

int main()
{

```
char m;
int c, player=1, i, j;
printf("\t Tic\tTac\tToe\n");
printf("   \t player 1[X] \t player 2[O]\n\n");
do {
    srand(time(0));
    board();
    if(player%2==1) {
        player=1;
    }
    else {
        player=2;
    }
    printf("\nplayer %d: ",player);
    scanf("%d", & c);

    if(player==1) {
        m='X';
    }
    else if(player==2) {

        m='O';
    }
    if(c==1 && s[1]=='1')
        s[1]=m;
    if(c==2 && s[2]=='2')
        s[2]=m;
    if(c==3 && s[3]=='3')
        s[3]=m;
    if(c==4 && s[4]=='4')
        s[4]=m;
    if(c==5 && s[5]=='5')
        s[5]=m;
    if(c==6 && s[6]=='6')
        s[6]=m;
    if(c==7 && s[7]=='7')
        s[7]=m;
    if(c==8 && s[8]=='8')
        s[8]=m;
    if(c==9 && s[9]=='9')
        s[9]=m;
    if(c>9) {
        printf("\nInvalid choose Try again\n");
        player--;
    }

    getchar();
    system("clear");
    i=check();
    dup();
    player++;
   a++;
} while(i==-1);
board();

if (i==1)
    printf("\n==>\aPlayer %d won\n\n ", --player);
if(i==0)
    printf("\n==>\aGame is draw\n");
if(j==1) {
    printf("\nInvalid choose Try again\n");
    player--;
}


return 0;
```

}

```
    void board()
 {
printf("\n         |    | \n");
 printf("       %c | %c  | %c\n", s[1],s[2],s[3]);
    printf("_________|____|_________\n");
    printf("         |    | \n");
    printf("       %c | %c  | %c\n", s[4],s[5],s[6]);
    printf("_________|____|_________\n");
    printf("         |    | \n");
    printf("       %c | %c  | %c\n", s[7],s[8],s[9]);

}
int check() {
    if(s[1]==s[2] && s[2]==s[3])
        return 1;
    if(s[4]==s[5] && s[5]==s[6])
        return 1;
    if(s[7]==s[8] && s[8]==s[9])
        return 1;
    if(s[1]==s[4] && s[4]==s[7])
        return 1;
    if(s[2]==s[5] && s[5]==s[8])
        return 1;
    if(s[3]==s[6] && s[6]==s[9])
        return 1;
    if(s[1]==s[5] && s[5]==s[9])
        return 1;
    if(s[3]==s[5] && s[5]==s[7])
        return 1;
    if(s[1]!='1'&& s[2]!='2' && s[3]!='3' && s[4]!='4'&& s[5]!='5'&& s[6]!='6'&& s[7]!='7'&& s[8]!='8'&& s[9]!='9')
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;

}
```

**I am a begginer so if the way I am questioning is wrong plz feel free to ask me I will try my best to tell you my issue.i tried a lot to execute a warning when player tries to enter the number that already has 'X' or 'Y' but I was unsuccessful with no clue to do it on correct way.**I was successful to make it possible for s[1] but I couldn't apply that for all as it would be long process to gradually make the condition for each and every blocks so i am here if anyone could tell me a less lengthy and in more useful way. Thanks, hoping to get some suggestions.

Comment: `if (s[c] == 'X' || s[c] == 'O' ) printf("\nInvalid choose Try again\n"); else s[c] = m;`

Comment: @kaylum won't it Tigger for every choice?

Comment: What do you mean? Don't you want it to run for every choice? That is, every time there is an input `c` you want to check whether `s[c]` already has a value in it.

Comment: Or perhaps you mean you need to check whether `c` is out of bounds. If so, yes you do need to check that. I just didn't show it for brevity. So the full check would be: `if (c > 9 || s[c] == 'X' || s[c] == 'O')`

Comment: @kaylum thanks for idea this worked [if (player==1 && s[c] == 'O'){
 printf("\nInvalid choose Try again\n"); 
player--;
} 
else if(player==2 && s[c] == 'X'){
printf("\nInvalid choose Try again\n"); 
player--; 
}]

Comment: `player==1 && s[c] == 'O')` That's not sufficient. It will not catch the case that player1 is trying to pick a spot that he/she has already previously picked. That is, you need to check for both `X` and `O` for both players. Please review my condition.

Comment: @kaylum I will review your condition

Comment: It can't be. Just think about it. If `s[c]` is `X` how can `s[c] == 'O'` catch that case?

Comment: @kaylum didn't think that thanks I will try

Comment: @kaylum but your condition triggers for first choice too

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "first choice". If you mean the first time an entry is picked then I don't see how that is possible. The first time an entry is picked `s[c]` will be a value other than `X` and `O`. That is, `1`, `2`, etc.

Comment: I mean like if it's player 1 choice to choose and if s[2] is already occupied by 'X' || 'Y' then show the warning